# I want to query into Mongodb using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, backend, pymongo

I want to find and update specific fields from mongodb using python(pymongo)
Below is the exact structure of db

```
id: 2
Name: "CHK-MG-3"
NumberOfWorkbenches: 170
AllocatedWorkbenches: 0
Benchbetails: Array (17)
            ~ 0: Object
              seatRowLabel: "A"
              IsRowspace: false
              ~ seats: Array (13)
                       0: object
                       key: "A_1"
                       status: "available"
                       BenchName: ""
                       IsAllocated: True
                       IsRequested: false
                       seatNo: ""
                       seatLabel: "" 
                       dir: ""
                       labelNo: "x12"
                       team: ""
                       AllocationData: Array (1)
                                       0:Object
                                       id:111
                                       Program:"STL"
                                       Duration:"3 days"
                                       Team:"Frankestein"
```

First i want to find Name:"CHk-MG-3",then under the benchdetails, and inside seats(array) check for labelNo:x12 and update isallocatedto: false and AllocationData to None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this query using [arrayFilters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) twice because the nested array:

With this query you are telling mongo:

- Do the update only into objects where `Name` is `CHK-MG-3`or has a property inside `Benchbetails.seats.labelNo` with value `x12`. Using this you can avoid to filter the entire collection into `arrayFilters` stage.
- Then update values where `bench.seats.seat` is defined just below.
- `bench` is the object in the `Benchbetails` array where `seats.labelNo` is `x12` and `seat` is the object into `seats` array where `labelNo` is `x12`.

So you are updating only the desired value into nested array setting `IsAllocated` as `False` and `AllocationData` as `None`.

```py
collection.update_many(
    {
        "Name": "CHK-MG-3",
        "Benchbetails.seats.labelNo": "x12"
    },
    {
        "$set": {
            "Benchbetails.$[bench].seats.$[seat].IsAllocated": False,
            "Benchbetails.$[bench].seats.$[seat].AllocationData": None
        }
    },
    array_filters=[
        {"bench.seats.labelNo": "x12"},
        {"seat.labelNo": "x12"}
    ]
)
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iQ7cZQDPIrm)

Comment: i want to do the same with python (pymongo)

Comment: What do you need? Check [pymongo documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#getting-a-collection). I've used `collection` name as standard and API method `update_many`.